# MS SQL Advanced Select where something has been swapped

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

My problem is that I need to find clients who has been swapped between two companies for more than 2 times, so:

We have company A and B with Ids for example 1 and 2.
The Client has been swapped from company A to B, it has been logged to another table History.

Now i need to Select clients who has beed swapped from company A to B THEN from company B to A and THEN again from company A to B (in the end two swaps)

I need to say that I dont know how to do it. Any ideas?
Many thanks for every answer.

Edit:

@jarlh example:

```
Table Clients
ID        Name       CompanyId
1         Pikachu     63
2         Mew          34
3         Reptide     63
```

Table History

```
ID   ClientId   CompanyId
1     1            34
2     1            63
3     1            34
4     1            63
5     2            34
6     2            73
7     2            34
8     2            34
9     3            34
10    3            84
11    3             63
12    3            34
13    3            34
14    3            63
```

Result:

```
Id       ClientId
1        1
2        3
```

Comment: Add table definitions, some sample table data and the expected result. And show us your query attempt.

Comment: Do you only have two companies? Is it exactly three swaps or more than two? Is it always A, then B, then A (or is that just an example)?

Comment: @Frode In database I have more companies, but I need only to get out swaps between two specific one (static id like in example company A id 34 and company B id 63

Comment: And there are never more than 2 different CompanyId's for a ClientId?

Comment: @jarlh There is, look at example for client number 3 he was in CompanyId 34 then 84, then he moved to 63, back to 34 and then again 34 (its possible to contract again in same company) and then he moved to 63 again, thats the place where script should result him because he was in 34, then ignore 84 (WHERE clause?) he went to 63, moved back to 34 and in the end hes in 63 again.

Comment: @Zefurion . . . What does "swap" have to do with the data you have provided?  It is totally unclearly to me why 1 and 3 are chosen.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Look nr 3 at CompanyId. First 34 > 84 (ignore) > 63 > 34 > 34 > 63
In the end he was 34 > 63 > 34 > 63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two companies are fixed, and you only want one direction A->B->A and don't care about B->A->B, you can find from History all that have Company B and existed in A both before and after that.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM HistoryTable ht
WHERE CompanyID = 63 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HistoryTable h1 
            WHERE h1.ClientID = ht.ClientID 
            AND h1.CompanyID = 34
            AND h1.ID < ht.ID)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HistoryTable h2 
            WHERE h2.ClientID = ht.ClientID 
            AND h2.CompanyID = 34
            AND h2.ID > ht.ID)
```

**EDIT:** With 3 swaps, it get a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT * FROM HistoryTable ht 
WHERE CompanyID IN (63,34)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HistoryTable h1 
            WHERE h1.ClientID = ht.ClientID 
            AND h1.CompanyID IN (34,63)
            AND h1.CompanyID <> ht.CompanyID
            AND h1.ID < ht.ID)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HistoryTable h2 
            WHERE h2.ClientID = ht.ClientID 
            AND h2.CompanyID IN (34,63)
            AND h2.CompanyID <> ht.CompanyID
            AND h2.ID > ht.ID
            AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HistoryTable h3 
                        WHERE h3.ClientID = h2.ClientID 
                        AND h3.CompanyID IN (34,63)
                        AND h3.CompanyID <> h2.CompanyID
                        AND h3.ID > h2.ID))
```

I also added for swaps in both directions.
In case of A->B->A->B, ht table should represent the B - 2nd company, and we check if exists A before it (h1), and if there is A after it (h2) which also have B after itself (h3)

Comment: I need Clients who traveled
A->B->A->B
or
B->A->B->A

Comment: @Zefurion: OK, there are ways to do it, you can join HistoryTable 4 times and filter on it (easy way but not pretty for performance), or you can use LAG() functions. I'll see to get you those sample codes in different answers if I get the time for it

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is just to join your history table on itself 4 times and use joins and where to filter results. It will work, but is very horrible performance-wise. Use it only if you don't have a lot of data or are not in rush.

```
SELECT * FROM HistoryTable h1
INNER JOIN HistoryTable h2 ON h2.ClientID = h1.ClientID 
                           AND h2.Id >h1.ID 
                           AND h2.CompanyID <> h1.CompanyID
INNER JOIN HistoryTable h3 ON h3.ClientID = h2.ClientID 
                           AND h3.Id >h2.ID 
                           AND h3.CompanyID = h1.CompanyID
INNER JOIN HistoryTable h4 ON h4.ClientID = h3.ClientID 
                           AND h4.Id >h3.ID 
                           AND h4.CompanyID = h2.CompanyID
WHERE h1.CompanyID IN (34,63)
AND h2.CompanyID IN (34,63)
```

Comment: Problem is that I have a lot of data, over 100k in history... And in the end I need only result Clients who has situation IN history table like A>B>A>B.
I was thinking about using Select in Select or Select in Where clause, but i dont know if I am right and if its possible to do. Many thanks for answer so far!

Comment: In the end: there Is no quick way to filter 100k rows, and either way you need to check all of them - and multiple times.

Comment: Maybe you split upper query into 4 queries where you filter a new #temp table in between. Fill the 1st #temp table with possible clients that worked in either company. Then Join to find out those who switched once and fill 2nd# temp table.. and so on..

Comment: Is it possible to do A->B->A->B by the AND EXISTS like You did below?

Comment: @Zefurion Yes, but with 3 changes it would get somewhat more complicated. You would need nested Exists in subqueries. I'll try to rewrite it for you.